# Getting value from populated drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

I have populated a drop down list from the database but i dont think the value is being set to the name the user chooses from the drop down as when the form is selected, no value is added to the database.

At the moment, it shows all the names from that table. As i said, i want the value to be the name the user chooses so that when the form is submitted it is added to the database and can be fetched on another page.

```
<select name="category">
<?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT category_Name FROM category");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo '<option value="'.$category_Name.'">' . $row['category_Name'] . "</option>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<option value="'.$category_Name.'">' . $row['category_Name'] . "</option>";
                    // ^ this var is never set
```

should be

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['category_Name'].'">' . $row['category_Name'] . "</option>";
//                       ^ change this
```

or you can just have it like this

```
echo '<option>' . $row['category_Name'] . "</option>";
```

If value is not set, it just takes the value of the display name.